# Update on change doesn't work Angular-CLI (ng-serve)

Tags: node.js, angular-cli

I recently changed from my windows machine to an iMac, I copied my angular projects to the Mac and followed al the installation instructions, but now when I type NPM start, the project starts, but does not update when i save a file.

I already uninstalled angular-cli and installed it to the newest version

**angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.21**

**node: 6.9.1**

**os: darwin x64**

Also i installed watchman, but no succes.

When i kill ng serve, the site directly giving errors

> zone.js:1382 GET
>   http://localhost:4200/sockjs-node/info?t=1480327234430
>   net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

So it is watching i guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They recently updated one of the names for the output files the CLI generates.  The change was from "inline.js" to "inline.bundle.js".

Answer (score 2):

For me, using `ng serve --poll=2000` was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with WebStorm and Vim
due to an IDE "safe write" feature writing files to a tmp file

When you edit and save a file the change is detected but
the page in the browser is not updated.

Vim fix
Add the following to the .vimrc
:set backupcopy=yes

WebStorm fix
System Settings and uncheck 'Use "safewrite"

ref: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5831